# hadoop fs commands are showing the local filesystem not the hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I installed hadoop in several laptops in order to form a hadoop cluster. First we installed in pseudo-distributed mode, and in all except one verything was perfect (i.e. all the services run, and when I do tests with `hadoop fs` it shows the `hdfs`). In the aftermentioned laptop (the one with problems) the `` `hadoop fs -ls ``command shows the information of the local directory *not* the `hdfs`, the same happens with the commands `-cat`, `-mkdir`, `-put`. What could I be doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated

Here is my `core-site.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
 <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
 <value>/home/hduser/hdfs_dir/tmp</value>
 <description></description>
</property>

<property>
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
 <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
 <description>.</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I must said, that this is the same file for all the other laptops, and they work fine.

Comment: can you share the core-site.xml file . Would like to know if you have changed the default value for property "fs.default.name" from its default file:///

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, and I had to make sure `fs.default.name`'s value included a trailing `/` to refer to the path component:

```
<property>
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
 <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/</value>
 <description>.</description>
</property>
```

Comment: Let me try it, and I will come back to you ...  :)

Answer (score 4):

check that `fs.default.name` in `core-site.xml` points to the correct datanode
in ex:

```
<property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>
     <value>hdfs://target-namenode:54310</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

If `fs.default.name` in `core-site.xml` points to    `hdfs://localhost:54310/` with or without trailing  `/` and even if you have same problem then you might be looking at wrong config file. In my case it is cloudera's cdh4 and check the symbolic links:

`ls -l /etc/hadoop/conf

** /etc/hadoop/conf -> /etc/alternatives/hadoop-conf

ls -l /etc/alternatives/hadoop-conf

** /etc/alternatives/hadoop-conf -> /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn1`

Earlier I used MRv1 and migrated to MRv2 (YARN) and the sym links were broken after upgrade as:

`ls -l /etc/hadoop/conf

** /etc/hadoop/conf -> /etc/alternatives/hadoop-conf

ls -l /etc/alternatives/hadoop-conf

** /etc/alternatives/hadoop-conf -> /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce1

ls -l /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce1

ls: cannot access /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce1: No such file or directory`

Also, update-alternatives was run to have high priority for /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce1 path as:

`` alternatives --display hadoop-conf

hadoop-conf - status is manual.

 link currently points to /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce1

/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.hdfs1 - priority 90

/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce1 - priority 92

/etc/hadoop/conf.empty - priority 10

/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn1 - priority 91

Current `best' version is /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce1. ``

To remove old link which has highest priority do:

update-alternatives --remove hadoop-conf /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce1
rm -f /etc/alternatives/hadoop-conf
ln -s /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn1 /etc/alternatives/hadoop-conf