# HDFS: Removing directories

Tags: hadoop, directory, hdfs

I did this: `hadoop fs -ls /`

It's showing me all the directories under / that has the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS), which are:

```
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2016-04-23 02:08 /etc
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2016-04-23 03:21 /home
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2016-04-23 03:15 /sqoop
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2016-04-24 02:28 /sqooptest
drwx-wx-wx   - hduser supergroup          0 2016-04-08 22:23 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2016-04-25 00:50 /user
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2016-04-08 22:33 /usr
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2016-04-24 02:33 /var
```

Is that correct? If so, I would like to know what will happen if I do this:

```
hadoop fs -rm -r /etc /home /sqoop /sqooptest /tmp /usr /var
```

which is essentially removing the all those directories (with the exception of `/user` because I need it). Will it cause a problem? If so, what? I wanted a clean slate so I am trying to remove everything HDFS. This is for my sqoop stuff.

I just don't want my computer to crash.

I've not `-rm -r`'d anything yet because I need an expert advice.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: It's looks like your local file system, not HDFS. To get list of files in HDFS you should try to run something like `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:<your hdfs port here>/`. Check this topic for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801444/hadoop-fs-commands-are-showing-the-local-filesystem-not-the-hdfs

Answer (score 2):

That looks fine at first glance.

The reason `-rm -r` is appropriately frightening is that it's a command you really don't want to mess up, since it will delete everything underneath where you start.  The `-r` in `-rm` command means "recursive", in other words, everything in that directory and all files and directories included.  If directory "foo" contained "bar" and "bar" contained "fubar" and that contained the file "do-not-delete-on-pain-of-death.txt" you would have a path like `/foo/bar/fubar/` containing the `.txt` file.  Just be aware that if you ran `hadoop fs -rm -r /foo` you would blow away `foo` and everything underneath.

What you really don't want to do is something like `hadoop fs -rm -r /etc / sqoop` -- see how I mistakenly put a space between the `/` and `sqoop`?  That would be bad since it's saying delete `/etc` then delete everything under `/` (root) at which point you're feeling very hopeful that Hadoop's trashcan works.

So, assuming you can part with everything in and under `/etc /home /sqoop /sqooptest /tmp /usr /var` your command is ok.

But if this is in any way fuzzy or you're not sure, create a directory like "temptest" and create a few subdirectories underneath with one you don't want to delete.  `rm -r` is the nuclear bomb of filesystem commands.  Make sure you know how to turn the key :-).  Not to be overly alarming or anything...